# Passing object to Query plugin which includes data from the element applied to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass an object to some jQuery plugin.  The plugin is applied to multiple elements.  The data passed is obtained from the element the plugin is applied to.

How can I pass such an object to a Query plugin which includes data from the element applied to (i.e. `$(this).parent().parent().data('id')`)?

EDIT.  without iterating over the results and applying the plugin each time.

```
$('#main').find('tr a.upload').fileupload({
    formData: {id:$(this).parent().parent().data('id'),foo:'bar'},  //id is not included
    start: function() {
        //Doesn't work
        $(this).fileupload({
            formData: {example: 'test'}
        });
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        console.log(this);  //Am able to access element
    },
});
```

Comment: It depends on the plugin. Some plugins allow some options to be functions, and they'll call the function on the element to get the value.

Comment: @Barmar  Ah, so it is plugin specific.  Didn't think it would be.  If the specific plugin doesn't support, guess I will go with my two step approach of iterating over them with `each`, and then applying them.  Thank you

Comment: This is most often done with options whose value might change dynamically. They don't call the function until they need it, so the function can return the appropriate value at that time.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it is possible to do so, but not sure how.  I tried `formData: function(form){return {id:$(this).parent().parent().data('id'),foo:'bar'}},` without success.

Comment: Which plugin is this, can you add a link to the doc?

Comment: The pluin is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options.  I might have found a solution, but not sure if it is really the right way.  `.on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {data.formData={id:$(this).parent().parent().data('id'),foo:'bar'};})`

Comment: In your earlier comment, change `$(this).parent()` to `form.parent()`.

Comment: Tried.  `form` was an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#main').find('tr a.upload').fileupload({
    formData: function(form) {
        return {
            id: form.parent().parent().data('id'),
            foo:'bar'
        };
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        console.log(this);  //Am able to access element
    },
});
```

The function is received the form as a parameter, not as the `this` context.